# Change keyboard layout and input language in a terminal on Ubuntu Droplet in Digital Ocean (English, Russian, Japanese)

Tags: terminal, keyboard, input, language

I spun up a Digital Ocean Ubuntu Droplet and I ssh to that machine from both my home and office.

I need to type in English, Russian and Japanese from a Mac Japanese keyboard from home and a US 106 keyboard in the office.

Questions:

1. How do I change keyboards in the remote terminal (I do not use GUI) when I log in to the droplet via SSH?
2. How do I install an input system for Russian and Japanese and how to switch between English, Russian and Japanese in the terminal when I make notes in VIM?
3. How do I add UTF-8 system fonts and install so that I can run Japanese terminal programs as well?